# xAxis in MP Android Chart getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?) value showing negative -1

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, mobile-development

How to solve the problem where the value in xAxis Mpcharts is -1? Because of this problem, my first array in xAxis is not showing.

```
 inner class MyAxisFormatter : IndexAxisValueFormatter() {

    override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        var xValue = ""
        val index = value.toInt()
        Log.d("Main Activity", "value: " + value)
        xValue = if (index < Month_AmountArrayList.size && index > 0) {
            Month_AmountArrayList[index].month

        } else {
            ""
        }
        return xValue


    }
}
```

2 elements in the array:

[image: element object]

The output in logcat:

[image: logcat output]

The output in phone:

[image]

chart output not showing Jan

Comment: Please don't post images of text